# Need Regular expression to replace RTF control word with in text. Java

Tags: java, regex

I have an String in which tags can appear inside caret sysmbol like `^...^`. I found a regular expression that can find tags in String like `\\^.*?\\^`. Now after finding tags my tags can contain RTf control words. It's not always but in some cases it can. Here is an example of such tag `^L\\hich\\af39\\dbch\\af31505\\loch\\f39 OT-CITY^`. Now I want to replace RTF control word in this tag. For this I tried to make a regular expression that can start with `\`, can contain letters or numbers or both after slash and ends with space. And replace it with empty `""`. In this way I just have `LOT-CITY` remains. How can I do it. I tried the following

```
String tagRegex = "\\^.*?\\^";
Pattern tagRegexPattern = Pattern.compile(tagRegex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher tagRegexPatternMatcher = tagRegexPattern.matcher(input);
while(tagRegexPatternMatcher.find()) {   // work
    String tag = tagRegexPatternMatcher.group();
    String controlWordRegex = "\\b\\[a-zA-Z]+(-?[0-9]+)? ? \\b";
    Pattern controlWordRegexPattern = Pattern.compile(controlWordRegex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher controlWordRegexPatternMatcher = controlWordRegexPattern.matcher(tag);
    while (controlWordRegexPatternMatcher.find()) {  // didn't work
        String matchedText = controlWordRegexPatternMatcher.group();
    }
}
```

Here is the input that I tried with

```
String input = "{\\rtlch\\fcs1 \\af39\\afs20 \\ltrch\\fcs0 \\fs20\\insrsid10175635\\charrsid8585274 \\hich\\af39\\dbch\\af31505\\loch\\f39 Build Job City:\\par \\hich\\af39\\dbch\\af31505\\loch\\f39 ^L\\hich\\af39\\dbch\\af31505\\loch\\f39 OT-CITY^}";
```

I tried the following too `\\b\\[a-zA-Z0-9]+ \\B`. Also with boundary and unboundary matches. But didn't get it work. How can I make such regular expression ?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this demo](https://ideone.com/wA5QlN).

Comment: It worked. Awesome. Post your answer So I can accept it. But let me understand it too. You start with word boundary. Then you made a group. Inside group you use `?:\\\\`. What does that mean ? Then you say a-z A-Z can appear one or more times. Then you made a group. In this group you say can contain `-` once or not at all. Can contain `0-9` one or more times. Group close and this group can present one or more time. Have a space and boundary ends. Am I understand it correctly ?

Comment: The `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group that does not keep submatches in the memory, it is only used for grouping patterns, so as to quantify them as a seuqence or group alternatives. Note that to match a ``\``, one needs to use 4 backslashes in the string literal regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to solve the issue:

```
String input = "{\\rtlch\\fcs1 \\af39\\afs20 \\ltrch\\fcs0 \\fs20\\insrsid10175635\\charrsid8585274 \\hich\\af39\\dbch\\af31505\\loch\\f39 Build Job City:\\par \\hich\\af39\\dbch\\af31505\\loch\\f39 ^L\\hich\\af39\\dbch\\af31505\\loch\\f39 OT-CITY^}";
String tagRegex = "\\^(.*?)\\^";
Pattern tagRegexPattern = Pattern.compile(tagRegex, Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher tagRegexPatternMatcher = tagRegexPattern.matcher(input);
while(tagRegexPatternMatcher.find()) {   // work
    String tag = tagRegexPatternMatcher.group(1);
    String controlWordRegex = "\\b(?:\\\\[a-zA-Z]+(-?[0-9]+)? ?)+ \\b";
    System.out.println(tag.replaceAll(controlWordRegex, ""));
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/wA5QlN)

First, I added a capturing group in the initial regex to grab the text between `^` symbols.

Then, the second regex matches

- `\\b` - a word boundary (there must be start of string or a word char before)
- `(?:\\\\[a-zA-Z]+(-?[0-9]+)? ?)+` - a non-capturing group (`(?:....)`, used only to group patterns to match them as a sequence) matching 1 or more sequences of:

  - `\\\\` - a `\`
  - `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1 or more letters
  - `(-?[0-9]+)?` - an optional sequence of an optional `-` and then 1+ digits
  - `?` - an optional space (replace with `\\s` for safety)
- `\\b` - a leading word boundary (there must be end of string or a word char after)

This regex is used inside a `.replaceAll` method to remove the RTF codes from the matches obtained with the first regex.